# Не сохраняется запись

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, пытаюсь сохранить **fabricators_id**  в таблицу **users**, но ничего не сохраняется.

Контроллер:

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $usermodel = AuthAssignment::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->one();
    if ($usermodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        if ($usermodel->validate() && $model->validate()) {
            if ($usermodel->save() && $model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'usermodel' => $usermodel,
    ]);
}
```

Представление:

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'fabricators_id')->dropDownList(Fabricators::getParam('name'))
?>
```

Модель не трогал, т.к. простейшая замена значения поля, однако возникли проблема.

afterSave:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
        if ($changedAttributes) {
            $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
            $user = $auth->getRole('user');
            $auth->assign($user, $this->id);
        }
}
```

Comment: Проверяйте доходит ли до `$model->save()`

Comment: @robertobadjo, как именно? не совсем понимаю

Comment: У Вас до редиректа  доходит или нет? Модели сохраняются?

Comment: @robertobadjo, да, до редиректа доходит, модель $usermodel сохраняется, а модель $model - нет. возможно это из-за метода afterSave в ней, но там я добавил проверку. приложу к вопросу.

Comment: Если бы модель `$model` не сохранилась, редиректа бы не было

Comment: я это понимаю, однако модель не сохраняется. возможно где то опечатался, перепроверю еще раз.

Comment: Проверяйте присваивается ли новое значение полю `fabricators_id` после `$model->load`. После валидации, проверьте ошибки `$model->errors`

Comment: Возможно атрибут `fabricators_id` не `safe`

Comment: @robertobadjo, зачем делать его safe? в модель я передаю выбранный элемент массива типа integer, модель $usermodel все прекрасно принимает и сохраняется

Comment: Ну сделайте `var_dump` модели на каждом шаге, посмотрите присваивается ли новое значение вашему атрибуту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы: прописать `['fabricators_id', 'required'],` в `rules` в модели `Users`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй передать в dropDownList отформатированный массив

```
ArrayHelper::map(Fabricators::find()->all(),'id','name')
```

Ещё попробуй отключить валидацию

```
$usermodel->save(false) && $model->save(false)
```

Comment: да, про массив знаю. создал метод, собирающий массива. его и вызываю в представлении. и это не помогло.

Comment: Валидацию проходит?

Comment: да, валидацию проходит.